Timestamp is missing in pyplot graph
I am beginner python learner. I am trying to plot a basic time vs power generation graph using Matplotlib.pyplot. I converted my date_time input data from string to date time object. When I plot it the 'time' part goes missing. I want the whole date and time part in the xticks.
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig , ax1 = plt.subplots()
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y\n%H:%M:%S')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax1.plot(date_time, generation)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.grid()

The above code gives the graph below[enter image description here]
(https://i.sstatic.net/Mmbd8dpB.png)
The 'date_time' column that goes in the x-axis has following data as sample
3    2024-03-01 00:04:05
14   2024-03-01 22:20:30
13   2024-03-02 03:56:23
16   2024-03-03 22:33:51
10   2024-03-04 14:46:24
31   2024-03-04 20:48:52
29   2024-03-05 01:31:23
4    2024-03-07 23:21:16

Please help me out to print the date and time part in x axis. Thank you

the code is missing necessary imports.

the code has undefined variables date_time, generation, so what are these ?

there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

You can use set_xticks() and pass your list of data (datetime) as an argument.
Maybe you will use autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)  to rotate the date labels for better readability.
Here is the modified code:
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig , ax1 = plt.subplots()
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y\n%H:%M:%S')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax1.set_xticks(date_time)  # Set x-axis ticks exactly at the date_time points
ax1.plot(date_time, generation)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)  # Rotate the date as you like
plt.grid()

Here is the full code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

# Provided your data as date_time strings and corresponding generation values
data = [
    ("2024-03-01 00:04:05", 3),
    ("2024-03-01 22:20:30", 14),
    ("2024-03-02 03:56:23", 13),
    ("2024-03-03 22:33:51", 16),
    ("2024-03-04 14:46:24", 10),
    ("2024-03-04 20:48:52", 31),
    ("2024-03-05 01:31:23", 29),
    ("2024-03-07 23:21:16", 4)
]

date_time = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for date, _ in data]
generation = [gen for _, gen in data]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y\n%H:%M:%S')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

ax1.set_xticks(date_time)
ax1.plot(date_time, generation)

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)

plt.grid()
plt.show()


the code posted as an answer can not work. did you even try it ?  it is missing imports and has undefined variables. This cannot possibly be an answer.

@D.L The code is written in the same way as the code in the question, to clarify the solution.
